# Use a USB mouse for DOS games

Tags: ms-dos, mouse

I have a Thinkpad T41 on which I installed Windows 98 SE.
I installed an old DOS game, and was wondering if I could get a USB mouse to work with it ? (the PC doesn't have a PS/2 port)

At the moment, my USB mouse doesn't even work on Windows, I'm going to try to buy an older one.
Touchpad is working on Windows, but not on DOS.

What are my options ?

Comment: You might want to look if the BIOS offers a USB legacy setting. On some machines this will translate USB mouse handling to emulate a serial mouse. Also, it may be an idea to ask in a thinkpad related support area, they usually know well what to do.

Answer (score 6):

To get your mouse working under DOS, you can try [Bret Johnson’s USB programs](http://bretjohnson.us/) — you’ll need one of the `USBUHCI` drivers, `USBMOUSE`, and [CuteMouse](http://cutemouse.sourceforge.net/).

Given how `USBMOUSE` works, it might also allow Windows 98 to use it, but I haven’t tried that.